# Como fazer um filtro de busca

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, algoritmo-de-busca

Tenho uma página de consulta que mostra em forma de tabela os registros cadastrados no banco através de um formulário.

Tendo em vista que vai chegar um ponto que o sistema vai ter muitos cadastros, achei sensato fazer um campo de busca, mas não sei bem por onde começar.

**Consulta.php:**

```
<h1 style="
    text-align: center;
    height: 7;
    margin-top: 150;
    margin-bottom:70;
"> Consulta de formações </h1>

<body>
<form method="post" >
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NOME">Nome: </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="NOME" placeholder="Nome do colaborador" name="NOME">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 24;">Buscar</button>
</form>
<!--Filtro de busca-->
<?php

$nome = $_POST['NOME'];

if($nome!=""){
    $lnk = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysql_error());  

    $sql1 = "SELECT * from formacoes where locate('$nome',NOME)>0 order by NOME asc";
    $query = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

    if(@mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){ // Verifica se o SQL retornou algum registro
?>
Encontrado registros com <?php echo $nome ?>:
<br><br>
<?php
    while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ //loop para exibir na página os registros que foram encontrados
?>
<?php echo $dados['nome']?>
<br>
<?php
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }else{
?>
Nada encontrado com <?php echo $nome ?>
<br><br>
<?php
    }
    mysql_close($lnk);
}
?>

<!--Tabela com as buscas-->
<?php
//Conexão e consulta ao Mysql
mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('db_formacao') or die(mysql_error());
$qry = mysql_query("select * from formacoes");

 $nome = $_POST['NOME'];
 $sql = (" SELECT * FROM formacoes WHERE NOME LIKE '%".$nome."%'");
//Pegando os nomes dos campos
$num_fields = mysql_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado

for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
    $fields[] = mysql_field_name($qry,$i);
}

//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de exclusão
    $table .= '<td><form action="banco/deleteF.php" method="post">'; 
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<button  class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>'; 
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

**A imagem da danada:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Agora o erro novo (mais bonitinho que o anterior):**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Essa é a minha terrivelmente falha tentativa de fazer um filtro de busca, se alguém puder me indicar uma maneira melhor (ou pelo menos funcional) de fazer isso, seria ótimo! :)

Comment: Vc quer fazer isso via Ajax ou enviar um POST pra própria página?

Comment: Por POST, não entendo de Ajax. :)

Comment: Na página aonde será enviado o campo NOME vc pesquisa no banco de dados as ocorrências: `$sql = "SELECT FROM tabela WHERE LOCATE('$nome', coluna) > 0";`. O LOCATE() retorna maior que 0 se qualquer registro na coluna informada houver o que foi enviado pelo campo NOME da busca. Com isso, vc faz o loop com os resultados obtidos, no HTML.

Comment: Não entendi bem a função desse LOCATE

Comment: O LOCATE() busca na coluna a string em `$nome`. Se houver, retorna a posição de `$nome` na string, caso contrário, 0. Vou colocar uma resposta de exemplo daqui a pouco.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá uma olhada nesse código, tu vai perceber que fiz algumas alterações, para deixar o fluxo mais simples. Principal foi unificar a parte que renderiza a tabela.

Tive que usar outra lib por que no meu ambiente a mysql não roda mais, somente a mysqli, essa mudança tu pode ignorar.

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);
    $lnk = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','') or die(mysqli_error()) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));
    mysqli_select_db($lnk,'sky_sirius') or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysqli_error($lnk));

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM formacoes ORDER BY nome ASC';
    $nome = @$_POST['NOME'];

    if(!is_null($nome) && !empty($nome)) 
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM formacoes WHERE nome LIKE '".$nome."' ORDER BY nome ASC";

    $qry = mysqli_query($lnk, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($lnk));
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
    $num_fields = @mysqli_num_fields($qry);//Obtém o número de campos do resultado
    $fields[] = array();
    if($num_fields > 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<$num_fields; $i++){//Pega o nome dos campos
            $fields[] = mysqli_fetch_field_direct($qry,$i)->name;
        }
    }
?>

<h1 style="
    text-align: center;
    height: 7;
    margin-top: 150;
    margin-bottom:70;
"> Consulta de formações </h1>

<body>
<form method="post" >
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NOME">Nome: </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="NOME" placeholder="Nome do colaborador" name="NOME">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 24;">Buscar</button>
</form>
<!--Filtro de busca-->

<?php
    if(!is_null($nome) && !empty($nome)) {
        if($count > 0) {
            echo 'Encontrado registros com o nome ' . $nome;
        } else {
            echo 'Nenhum registro foi encontrado com o nome ' . $nome;
        }
    }
?>

<!--Tabela com as buscas-->
<?php
//Montando o cabeçalho da tabela
$table = '<table class="table table-hover table-inverse" style="margin-top:50;background-color: #37444a; color:lightgrey;"> <tr>';

for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
    $table .= '<th>'.$fields[$i].'</th>';
}

//Montando o corpo da tabela
$table .= '<tbody style="
    background-color: #86979e;
    color: #37444a;    
">';
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($qry)){
    $table .= '<tr>';
    for($i = 0;$i < $num_fields; $i++){
        $table .= '<td>'.$r[$fields[$i]].'</td>';
    }

    // Adicionando botão de exclusão
    $table .= '<td><form action="banco/deleteF.php" method="post">'; 
    $table .= '<input type="hidden" name="ID" value="'.$r['ID'].'">';
    $table .= '<button  class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>'; 
    $table .= '</form></td>';
}

//Finalizando a tabela
$table .= '</tbody></table>';

//Imprimindo a tabela
echo $table;

?>
```

Comment: Então, vi isso um pouquinho antes de ver seu comentário e alterei aqui, agora se conecta, mas não aparece os resultados. Vou editar a pergunta pro novo código

Comment: Vou editar minha resposta para tentar te ajudar.

Comment: A parte da consulta funcionou bem quando eu usei seu código em outra página e coloquei um action no form que leve até lá. A única coisa curiosa que aconteceu é que todo o css do meu bootstrap foi embora. :/

Answer (score 1):

Uma estrutura simples de busca que você deve adaptar no seu PHP e HTML:

Vamos supor que eu tenha no BD os registros na tabela `estudantes`:

```
id | nome | data_nascimento
---------------------------
1  | joao | 01/10/1980
---------------------------
2  | maria| 05/04/1986
---------------------------
3  | joao paulo | 03/04/1988
```

O código da página onde será feita a busca e exibido o resultado via POST especificado no `action` do formulário:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
</head>
<?php
$retorno_host = 'url_do_banco'; // Local da base de dados MySql
$retorno_database = 'nome_do_banco'; // Nome da base de dados MySql
$retorno_usuario = 'usuario'; // Usuario com acesso a base de dados MySql
$retorno_senha = 'senha';  // Senha de acesso a base de dados MySql

$nome = $_POST['NOME'];

if($nome!=""){
    $lnk = mysql_connect($retorno_host, $retorno_usuario, $retorno_senha) or die ('Nao foi possível conectar ao MySql: ' . mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($retorno_database, $lnk) or die ('Nao foi possível ao banco de dados selecionado no MySql: ' . mysql_error());  

    $sql1 = "SELECT * from estudantes where locate('$nome',nome)>0 order by nome asc";
    $query = mysql_query($sql1) or die(mysql_error());

    if(@mysql_num_rows($query) > 0){ // Verifico se o SQL retornou algum registro
?>
Encontrado registros com <?php echo $nome ?>:
<br><br>
<?php
        while($dados = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ //loop para exibir na página os registros que foram encontrados
?>
<strong>Nome:</strong> <?php echo $dados['nome']?>
<br>
<?php
        }
        echo "<br>";
    }else{
?>
Nada encontrado com <?php echo $nome ?>
<br><br>
<?php
    }
    mysql_close($lnk);
}
?>
<body>
<form method="post" action="teste.php">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="NOME">Nome: </label>
            <input class="form-control" id="NOME" placeholder="Nome do colaborador" name="NOME">
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top: 24;">Buscar</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Os resultados só serão exibidos caso o $_POST['NOME'] seja diferente de vazio:

```
if($nome!=""){
...
}
```

Do contrário, só será exibido na página o formulário de busca.

Pode testar com o BD acima neste link provisório: http://decknorte.com/teste.php

Comment: Nossa, complexo, mas muito bem explicado. Então, eu peguei seu código mas não usei o $retorno_host, mudando pra $retorno_database em $lnk. Além disso, não tirei a parte do meu código que gera a tabela porque preciso que algum resultado seja mostrado antes da busca. Até aí nenhum problema, mas quando eu vou testar dá "Objeto não encontrado". :/

Comment: Vou editar a minha pergunta pro código atual.